# Different SearchBox results from HERE API and old Nokia OVI API

Tags: javascript, here-api, search-box

I'm implementing an integration with brand new **HERE JavaScript places API** (version 2.5.3) particularly using nokia.places.SearchBox().

I noticed that the old OVI SearchBox component, used in the same way, provided results with an higher detail level than the new HERE SearchBox component.

e.g. typing "*oxford street london*" I'm getting "*Oxford Street, London, United Kingdom*" using OVI and only "*Oxford Street*" with HERE.

Is it possible to obtain the same results with HERE API without implementing other solutions (e.g. REST API with custom behavior)? Maybe passing a parameter to the SearchBox() function...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding the `showAddress` parameter.

Taking your example the following search box:

```
var fromSearchBox = new nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox({
        targetNode: "fromSearchBox",
        template: "fromSearchBox",
        map: map
    });
```

Returns the following responses to "*Oxford Street*" for a search centered on London

> - Results
>
>   - Oxford Street
>   - Oxford Street
>   - John Lewis Oxford Street

Adding in the `showAddress` parameter as shown:

```
var toSearchBox = new nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox({
        targetNode: "toSearchBox",
        template: "toSearchBox",
        map: map,
        suggestions : {showAddress: true}
    });
```

And the "*Oxford Street*" query gives me:

> - Results
>
>   - Oxford Street Southampton, SO14 3, United Kingdom
>   - Oxford Street Northwood, Cowes, PO31 8, United Kingdom
>   - Oxford Street Oxford Street, London,, United Kingdom

Further manipulation would be possible using the callbacks defined in the [SearchBox constructor](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox.html#topic-apiref__SearchBox-0), specifically the  `handlers` called `onSuggestions` and `onSearchSuggestions` could be useful.